# continue statement inside nested for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, nested-loops, continue

I don't understand what exactly does the continue statement inside this for loop do. How is code any different if I remove it? Which lines does it skip if it's placed at the end of for loop?

```
int sum = 0, i, j, stop = 0;
for( i = 1; i <= 5 && !stop; i++)
{
    for( j = 1; j <= 5 ; j++)
    {
        if (j%4 == 0)
        {
            stop = 1;
            continue;
        }
        sum += i+j;
    }
}
printf("%d\n", sum);
```

If you run this program the sum is going to be 15, and if you comment out countinue line then it's going to be 20.

Comment: Please indent your code properly, It is very hard to read as is.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/0ceyyskb.aspx

Comment: @dandan78 Formatting fixed. I myself didn't notice this due to bad formatting. Thanks all for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be more clear if you would format the code. Let's consider the inner loop

```
for( j = 1; j <= 5 ; j++)
{
    if ( j % 4 == 0)
    {
        stop = 1;
        continue;
    }

    sum += i+j;
}
```

Thus as you see if j % 4 == 0 then statement

```
sum += i+j;
```

is skipped.

As for the code in whole then it has no any sense.:) It is a silly code.

In fact your code is equivalent to the following

```
int sum = 0, j;

for( j = 1; j <= 5 ; j++ )
{
    if ( j != 4 ) sum += j + 1
}

printf("%d\n", sum);
```

So you will get sum 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 that is equal to 15.:)

Comment: and the I loop has no porpoise, since it will only loop once

Answer (score 2):

The continue statement skips the remainder of the current loop. In the case of nested loops, it skips to the next iteration of the innermost loop.

In this case, if you didn't continue, you would execute `sum += i+j;` in every iteration, where it appears you only want it sometimes.

That being said, this is a very awkward loop to begin with. The whole `stop` variable is rather ill conceived from the get-go anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The `continue` statement is used to start the next iteration of a loop,skipping everything in the loop,after the `continue`. In your case,once the execution of the program reaches the `continue` statement,then the next iteration of your inner loop starts,skipping whatever there was after the `continue`. It skips `sum += i+j;` as it is after the `continue` and the sum will not be added when `j` is 4 as `j%4` will be 0. This is why you get 20 when you comment the `continue` and 15 when you uncomment it.

P.S: Your outer loop will execute only once as `stop` will be changed inside the `if` in your inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

`continue` causes the enclosing `for` loop to begin the next iteration. As a more basic example, take the following code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    if(i % 2 == 1) // If it's odd
        continue;
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

In this case, the `continue` statement will cause the `for` loop to immediately begin the next iteration if `i` is odd, hence this code will print the even numbers between 0 and 50.

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum = 0, i, j, stop = 0;

for( i = 1; i <= 5 && !stop; i++)
{
   for( j = 1; j <= 5 ; j++)
   {
      if (j%4 == 0)                  <===== is j divisible by 4 ?
       {
          stop = 1;                  <=== set stop flag, will continue for J loop
                                         but stop next I loop and end the routine
          continue;         <==== skip the rest of the J loop for this itteration
       }

       sum += i+j;
    }
}

printf("%d\n", sum);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ceyyskb.aspx  explains the continue statement